# mktime returns the same value in different timezones PHP

Tags: php, timezone, mktime

Usually this question has the opposite sense. But, I've faced with problem that, somehow `mktime()` function in PHP always brings me UTC timestamp despite of changing default timezone. In other words having this simple page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div>
    <?php
    echo phpversion().'<br />';
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
    $script_tz = date_default_timezone_get();
    echo $script_tz.'<br>';
    $user_now = mktime();
    echo $user_now.'<br />'."\r\n";
    
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
    $script_tz = date_default_timezone_get();
    echo $script_tz.'<br>';
    $utc_now = mktime();
    echo $utc_now.'<br />'."\r\n";
    ?>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I receive this:

```
5.3.28<br>
America/Los_Angeles<br>
1556333103<br>
UTC<br>
1556333103<br>
```

as a result. As you can see the same value in different timezones.
You can make sure of it following the [page with that html code](http://sedecilliard.com)

I just lost the hope in the attempts to get different results instead. Please, give me a hand, tell me what am I doing wrong? Where to dig to find the cause?

Answer (score 2):

Timestamps are not affected by timezones (they are just the number of seconds since the unix Epoch, which is the same regardless of your timezone) so `mktime` returns the same value for the same time. However when you display that value (e.g. using `date`), you will see the difference from the two timezones:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
$script_tz = date_default_timezone_get();
echo $script_tz.'<br>';
$user_now = time();
echo $user_now.'<br />'."\r\n";
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $user_now).'<br />'."\r\n";

date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$script_tz = date_default_timezone_get();
echo $script_tz.'<br>';
$utc_now = time();
echo $utc_now.'<br />'."\r\n";
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $utc_now).'<br />'."\r\n";
```

Output:

```
America/Los_Angeles<br>1556334114<br /> 2019-04-26 20:01:54<br />
UTC<br>1556334114<br /> 2019-04-27 03:01:54<br />
```

Note that `mktime` [with no arguments has been deprecated](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php), you should just use `time` instead.

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/OhRHd)